# wiring multiple led flashlights to single power source

Tags: led

Last year we used cheap led flashlights to light our Halloween trail. They worked out well but, we bought a lot of batteries.

What I would like to do is hardwire these flashlights 30 ft apart and use one power source. It would be nice to go 500 to 1000 ft. Those distances may be crazy but I have no idea what is practical. So lets say 15 to 30 of these flashlights wired together.

The flashlights have 24 leds wired in parallel with one 22 ohm resister.

The main idea is to eliminate buying batteries. We hope to use these lights for several years.

So, is this possible, practical, or just crazy.

If it's possible and you need more info, just let me know

Thanks

Comment: Do you have ANY specifications about each flashlight? What voltage (how many batteries, what kind, etc) did you use before? If I assumed 20 mA per LED and your resistor, I'd have to imagine at least 12 V source voltage. But it would help a lot to have the voltage you used for them.

Comment: We used these last year, They worked when we took them down, They run on 3 AAA batteries.  I would like to run them on like a 12v or 24 v transformer

Comment: Do you have any preference with \$12\:\textrm{V}\$ vs \$24\:\textrm{V}\$? I'm going to guess that you already understand, then, that if you change the voltage at all then you will have to modify each flashlight to use that different voltage. What kind of modifications are you willing to make? Are you thinking of ONLY changing the resistor?

Comment: I have no preference on 12 or 24 volt.   I guess what I'm looking for is for someone to tell me how to wire a bunch of these to a single power source with a very long run of wire. What gauge wire? If resisters are needed what size? Should they be wired in series or parallel? I'm not opposed to some trial and error but I'd rather not burn them all up trying to come up with some that works

Comment: Let's say you jack up the voltage to 24 V. Your lanterns are set up for 4.5 V right now. So you could just change the resistor. But then you'd be wasting over 90% of the power. In effect, you'd need 10 times the current than you may otherwise need if you were more efficient. And this means cheaper and easier to use wire. I get \$\frac{4.5\:\textrm{V}-2\:\textrm{V}}{22\:\Omega}\cdot 24\approx 2.8\:\textrm{A}\$ for all those LEDs. Maybe \$\frac{1}{4}\$ amp at \$24\:\textrm{V}\$ if efficient. But nearly 3 A, if not. And you are talking about 1000 feet?

Comment: So I think my question about what kinds of modifications you are able and willing to consider comes back to the fore. If it is ONLY to change the resistor, then you are facing pushing a few amps through a lot of wire. If you are willing to make more extensive mods, then that's a different set of considerations. I'm just staring at 1000 feet of wire, out and then back, and wondering. You know? Especially since you brought up the idea of a higher voltage.

Comment: I'm not a complete novice but, pretty close. I can read schematics and solder it up but can't say what the components are actually doing. What do you call "extensive mods"?

Comment: Well, you could consider the idea of using a separate, tiny (and relatively cheap) buck converter for each flashlight. Run 24 V (AC or DC) on the wire and convert it down to the level you need. You'd still use the same (or similar) resistor. But the wire can be relatively thin and these cheap buck converters provide a screwdriver adjustment so they are easy to tweak. I would NOT consider the idea of a separate transformer at each flashlight, though. A DC to DC is probably the way I'd go. About $1 each, I think.

Comment: I like the sound of the converter. Can you send a link to what you are thinking of

Comment: Sure. But before I do that, I want to make sure you have NO INTEREST in trying to use mains power instead. An alternative, if this is a kind of permanent installation, is to run mains wiring underground in a cheap pipe on your trail and include tiny, sealed converters out of which either 3.3 V or 5 V leaves for use for each flashlight.

Comment: If you supply 24VDC down the wire, look up 'LM2596 3A DC to DC Buck Converter' on ebay. Should be able to find them for about $1 each, shipped. If you run mains power, look up 'HLK-PM01' (5 V) or 'HLK-PM03' (3.3 V) on ebay for an idea there. Those are about $3 each. But isolated and sealed. Should be relatively safe to use, together with proper wiring and physical design.

Comment: Either way, this allows for very low-current wiring and shouldn't involve much of a voltage drop along the way out to the very end. And even if there IS a drop, the buck converter won't care and will give consistent results up and down the wire.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  This set up will be used for at least this year. The talk is to move the trail to another area i the future but no definite date to move.  This is the kind of info I was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: Want me to summarize it for you and add some additional thoughts as an answer? Or is this sufficient?

Comment: Please do. I would be happy to hear it

Comment: The biggest cost and unknown is 1000' of cable , what gauge and therefore resistance , how will it be strung.  You may need rodent proof insulation. (Rodent's love PVC)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try and derive a simple answer for you, that can be understood without EE level math.
I assume that the torches you are using are White LEDs. If they are White then I would expect a forward voltage of about 3-3.5 V for the devices used.

[image]

All diodes have a slope in the Vf characteristics such that as the current through them increases, the forward voltage drop increases (in a non-linear fashion) too. You can see from the above graph that at a current of 5 mA for a White LED, Vf is about 3 V and at a current of 27.5 mA it's about 3.5 V.

The typical cheap Torch is powered by 3 * 1.5 V batteries, so the voltage available ranges from 4.5 V for fresh batteries to about 3 V for fully discharged batteries (1 V per cell). The brightness of the torch will drop as the batteries discharge. 
So again an assumption; you may be talking about cheap 24 LED torches such as this: 
[image]

If this is indeed somewhat similar to your torch, then **you have the series resistor wrong**. It's more likely to be 2.2 Ohms [than](http://resistor.cherryjourney.pt/) 22 Ohms. I have a bunch of these type torches and in mine the resistor is 2.6 Ohms.

To figure out how much current is flowing in 24 parallel LEDs is a bit of heavy math lifting to be accurate, but we can derive an approximation of the current in a very simple manner using just the graph above.

Here is the graph re-done to show the current and Vf for 24 LEDs in parallel.  Superimposed on this is the linear slope representing the current/voltage of the 2.2 Ohms limiting resistor I assume is in your torches.

[image]

The graph depends on a couple of assumptions:

1. The diodes are all identical Vf curves. ....they won't be, but they will be close enough to make this work.
2. Linear characterization of the Vf curve is good enough for an approximation of the total torch current.

From the above graph you can see that when the battery voltage is 4.5 V the current (LEDs and resistor) will be approximately 660 m A, and when the battery voltage is 3.5 V the current will be approximately 240 mA.

The power dissipation for a torch is then V * A --> 4.5 * 0.660 = 3 W. 
So each LED (if they shared the current equally) would be about 27.5 mA. This is about right as a maximum current for these small sized LEDs.

With your 30 torches at 3 W each you now also know you need about 90 W of power in total.

If you want to run 30 torches in parallel (using say a larger power supply to provide 4.5 V), then you'd have current flows of about 0.66 * 30 = 20 A. This could be done, but I consider it impractical (size of cables and voltage drop).

Now lets flip over to your garden situation. Most local regulations limit the voltage you can bury or expose to safety levels (typically 35-48 V AC or less). and with the prevalence of LED lighting today there are lots of good power supply options in the 12 V and 24 V DC range.

I'd suggest a waterproof 24 V DC exterior power supply may be a good starting point for your project. I'm not suggesting this particular unit, but it will give you an idea what to search for, Uxcell waterproof LED lighting supply [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01D2S307Q).

With a suitable 24 VDC power supply rated at 100 W or more (I'd recommend you use 150 W) you can run 5 torches in series (with a safety diode to lessen the likelihood you could blow any up with a reverse cable connection) and so have 6 cable runs to get your 30 units in total. Each torch now gets approximately 4.6 V which is right at the top of the range of our graph and shows a current per string of about 670 mA (less than 30 mA per LED, which is still within ratings).

If you want the torches to be dimmer you could run 6 torches in series per string (with 5 strings). This would result in approximately 3.8 V per torch and about 370 mA per string (about 16 mA per LED).
**Note:** You don't need to modify the torches at all, you simply connect 5 or 6 of them in series and they all have their own internal limiting resistor still in place.

Even though the power supply is short circuit protected, I'd suggest you add a 5 A output fuse (you can get [inline](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NQ8F242) fuse units) on the 24 VDC side so if you get any shorts in the garden you are protected. I'd further add an inline 1-2 A fuse on each of the series of torch strings.

So my suggested schematic would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHA4ga.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With a maximum current of about 4 A from the power supply and 0.66 A in each torch run you should be able to use any reasonable [garden/exterior rated cable](http://electracables.com.au/index.php?page=garden-lighting) of at least 10 A capacity (typically 10-16 AWG equivalent wire). The voltage drop in any particular cable should be kept to the minimum, but is going to be dependent on how many runs you have and the cable size you use. This will obviously be the most expensive part of your project since 1000 ft of cable is rarely cheap.
A good place to start for resistance values is this [chart](https://www.folsomlabs.com/modeling/modeling/wireresistance.JPG).
If you use 10 AWG wire (2 mOhm/ft) for the major spine from the power supply and 16 AWG (4 mOhm/ft) for the torch runs it should be possible to minimize the voltage drop to less than 0.5 V end to end.

Comment: With the exception of color that is exactly what we are using.  This is a lot to digest.   Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Safety is important.

24 volts distributed along the 500 feet, with further step down locally using other 117/24volt (6:1) to produce 4 volts AC RMS, would be quite safe and efficient.

Comment: So you can put a 24 volt transformer after another 24 volt transformer and take 120 down to 4 volts?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start out with a summary of my understanding of the problem.

The goal is to eliminate buying lots of batteries by centralizing the power source used for a system of between 15 and 30 lanterns, each separated by 30 feet, for a distance run that can be from 500 to 1000 feet long. These lanterns, in prior use, used a set of (3) AAA batteries and are very simple lanterns using one resistor of \$22\:\Omega\$ and (24) parallel-wired LEDs. (Parallel-wiring like that doesn't allow the LEDs to share current as well as they may, but it's how it was done and these are just lanterns so variations between the 24 LEDs is fine for this application.) Each lantern requires approximately:

$$I_{lantern}=\frac{4.5\:\textrm{V}-2\:\textrm{V}}{22\:\Omega}\le 125\:\textrm{mA}$$

---

Some options to consider:

1. Provide a centralized voltage rail with a current compliance of at least \$4.5\:\textrm{A}\$. The final voltage drop is \$V_{drop}=k_{wire}\cdot I_{lantern}\cdot\left(N^2+N\right)\cdot\frac{D}{1000'}\$, where D is the distance between each lantern, N is the number of lanterns, and \$k_{wire}\$ is the \$\frac{\Omega}{1000'}\$ for the wire being used. I get about \$2.5\:\textrm{V}\$ drop using 8 AWG copper wire and 30 lanterns, at the 30th lantern. This suggests a voltage rail of about \$7\:\textrm{V}\$ using 8 AWG copper. Or almost \$30\:\textrm{V}\$ using 18 AWG copper. And each lantern's resistor would need to be different, of course.
2. Provide a higher voltage DC rail and use a DC-to-DC converter at each lantern. From ebay, one can source LM2596 buck switching converters for about US$1 each. They include a voltage adjust potentiometer, as well, and work from a \$4-40\:\textrm{V}\$ rail. Because the sourcing current is so much less, and because the buck converter can handle a very wide range of input voltages, much lighter copper wire can be used for this application. 18 AWG copper would see about a \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ drop at the 30th lantern. A \$24\:\textrm{V}\$ supply would need to provide only about \$1\:\textrm{A}\$ current compliance. The lower current and wider range allowed for the input voltages to the converters means consistent voltage supply to each lantern and cheaper copper wire (which with 1000' of run does save some money.)
3. Provide a buried mains supply. Buried 1" pipe is about US$1 per 10'. But this would allow the use of sealed AC-to-DC HLK-PM01 \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ units, which are themselves another US$3 each from ebay. I would only consider this for a permanent installation, though. Trenching, pipe, etc. Fair amount of work for 1000' run. But another alternative.

Well, those are some directions that could be used without needing to modify the lanterns. If you are open to completely new lantern designs, then there are still more options to consider.

---

Since Passerby dragged my attention back here, might as well expose the computation for computing the voltage drop at the far-end of the line given periodic loads along a line. (I've no clue if there is a commonly used symbol for \$\frac{\Omega}{1000\:\textrm{ft}}\$, so I'm just calling it \$k_{wire}\$ for now. \$D\$ will be the total distance of the run. \$N\$ will be the number of periodic loads, which divide up the total distance into \$N\$ segments of wire. \$I_{load}\$ is the per-unit load. The first load is one segment downstream of the power source. The last load is at the very end.)

$$\begin{align*}
V_{drop} &= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left[I_i=I_{load}\cdot\left(N-i+1\right)\right]\cdot\left[R_i=2\cdot\frac{k_{wire}\cdot D}{1000\cdot N}\right]\\\\
V_{drop} &= I_{load}\cdot\left[2\cdot\frac{k_{wire}\cdot D}{1000\cdot N}\right] \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(N-i+1\right) \\\\
V_{drop} &= I_{load}\cdot\left[2\cdot\frac{k_{wire}\cdot D}{1000\cdot N}\right]\cdot\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{N} N-\sum_{i=1}^{N} i+\sum_{i=1}^{N}1\right] \\\\
V_{drop} &= I_{load}\cdot\left[2\cdot\frac{k_{wire}\cdot D}{1000\cdot N}\right]\cdot\left[ N^2-\sum_{i=1}^{N} i+N\right]\\\\
V_{drop} &= I_{load}\cdot\left[2\cdot\frac{k_{wire}\cdot D}{1000\cdot N}\right]\cdot\left[ \frac{N^2+N}{2}\right] \\\\
V_{drop} &= \left[I_{total}=I_{load}\cdot\frac{N+1}{2}\right]\cdot \left[R_{total}=2\cdot k_{wire}\cdot\frac{D}{1000}\right]
\end{align*}$$

This proves that it comes out very close to the natural presumption of using an average current that is one-half the total current (for large \$N\$) times the total wire resistance, out and back. But it never hurts to do the math to test common sense. (And to also see that it's not exactly the same, too.)

Comment: No need to bury. Landscape wiring uses free air 2 conductor cables.

Comment: @Passerby We bury around here -- local code says 18" dead minimum, with 24" recommended -- required for mains -- no exceptions.

Comment: How is 24V considered mains?

Comment: @Passerby The only item where I talked about burying is for mains. See #3. If I'm wrong about that, feel free to point out where and I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

AWG 16 is 4 Ohms /1000' per wire

If each LED @20mA ESR is 15 Ohms each and 30 LEDs in parallel = 0.5 Ohms 
Power consumed will possibly be 30*4.5V*0.02A=2.7W per light.

I think one 22 Ohm is an error in OP's comment
This would reduce LED current to 4.5-3V=1.5V then 1.5V/22R/30= 2.2mA per LED.

If each cluster of 30 LEDs 0.5 Ohm  @3V with  @4.5Vbat the single series R would be 1.5V/600mA = 0.2 Ohm ( or R22 in series is more likely )

AC to DC 3V without resistor would be most efficient if you can get reliable AC to 3V DC converters.

Personally I think it would be more economical to use sealed 6W PAR LED Lamps for < $3 with 5000K or Warm White 3300K with Edison socket and feed buried Line voltage.

No batteries and no transformer needed.

[image]